# How to get rid of the hardcoded sleep()?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

```
def textfield(boxid,textadded):
    project = driver.find_element_by_id(boxid)
    project.send_keys(textadded)
    sleep(3)

def dropdown(dropdownid, dropdownvalue):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownid))
    select.select_by_visible_text(dropdownvalue)
    sleep(5)
```

These 2 functions are functional however i'm using `sleep()` which is a bad practice since some my drop-downs and text fields will take longer than others to fill so i have to put the longest sleep value not to get errors, how can i fix these 2 functions using wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are invoking `send_keys()` on the *WebElement* **project**, ideally you should invoke *WebDriverWait* with *EC* as `element_to_be_clickable`, so you have to:

- Replace:

  ```
  def textfield(boxid,textadded):
      project = driver.find_element_by_id(boxid)
      project.send_keys(textadded)
      sleep(3)
  ```
- with:

  ```
  def textfield(boxid,textadded):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "boxid"))).send_keys(textadded)
  ```

As the drop-down take longer to fill so you should invoke *WebDriverWait* with *EC* as `visibility_of_element_located`, so you have to:

- Replace:

  ```
  def dropdown(dropdownid, dropdownvalue):
      select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownid))
      select.select_by_visible_text(dropdownvalue)
      sleep(5)
  ```
- with:

  ```
  def dropdown(dropdownid, dropdownvalue):
      select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "dropdownid"))))
      select.select_by_visible_text(dropdownvalue)
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [explicitly wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the element. Read more about waits [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Please note that this is not the official documentation.

```
#.....
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#......
select=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,dropdownid)))
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)!

You can use `presence_of_all_elements_located` on the list of select items...

An example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, dropdownid)))
```

Hope this helps!