# How to make selenium identify a button through an attribute within the HTML and click on it automatically whenever it is possible in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep, webdriverwait

Is it possible to make selenium identify an html button attribute and click on it. So whenever it finds a button attribute it clicks on it automatically. Because I always have to predict around how long it takes for the next button to appear and set `time.sleep()` but many times it results in errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of coarse it is possible to identify an html button through an attribute and invoke `click()` on it using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

But it won't be possible that, whenever a button is found through it's attribute, it can click on it automatically as:

- The prediction for how long to wait for the next button to be clickable should be part of your *Test Plan* or *Test Architecture* and should be part of the [specifications](/questions/tagged/specifications).
- Further, using `time.sleep(n)` **defeats the purpose of Automation** and should be avoided at any cost.

  > You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)
- Ideally, you need to remove the all the occurances of `time.sleep(n)` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).

  > You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to get rid of the hardcoded sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637664/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hardcoded-sleep/54637793#54637793)